# Converted Value Not Shown In The UI of GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a function that takes an object of storagefile and creates a thumbnail of it. This function is in the converter value since we have 10.000+ files that are going to be shown in a media gallery. The thumbnail will be generated on the file when the thumbnail is not yet created for the storage file.

The problem is, the UI of GridView is not updated once the thumbnail is generated / the object is updated. It will only show the thumbnail if I scroll down far enough and scroll back up again.

```
public class MediaFile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Declare the event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private ImageSource _thumbnail = null;

    public ImageSource Thumbnail
    {
        get { return _thumbnail; }
        set
        {
            _thumbnail = value;
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            OnPropertyChanged("Thumbnail");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    // The calling member's name will be used as the parameter.
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

This is the class of the so called MediaFile. As you can see I already implemented the property changed event.

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="GridMedia_DataTemplate" x:DataType="MediaFile">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource Faves_Grid}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0 14 0 -12" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource ThumbnailGenerator}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here is the data template for the grid view. As you can see, for the ImageSource we use converter to get / generate the thumbnail.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            if(value is MediaFile)
            {
                MediaFile file = value as MediaFile;
                //generate Thumbnail
                int width = 160;
                int height = 90;

                var pathFileTemp = $@"{FileLocations.MediaPath}";
                try
                {
                    StorageFile originalFile = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(pathFileTemp + file.Id).AsTask().Result;
                    if (originalFile != null)
                    {
                        //check extention
                        if (file.Extension.ToLower().Contains("pdf"))
                        {
                            GetThumbnailForPDF(file).GetAwaiter();
                            return file.Thumbnail;
                        }
                        else if (file.Extension.ToLower().Contains("jpg") ||
                            file.Extension.ToLower().Contains("gif") ||
                            file.Extension.ToLower().Contains("png") ||
                            file.Extension.ToLower().Contains("jpeg"))
                        {
                            GetThumbnailForImage(file).GetAwaiter();
                            return file.Thumbnail;
                        }
                    }
                    return new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Icon/placeholder_img.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                   return new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Icon/placeholder_img.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

As for now we only create thumbnail for pdf and images. Other than that we will return placeholder thumbnail.

```
        <controls1:AdaptiveGridView Grid.Row="1" DesiredWidth="288" x:Name="ListView_MediaLibrary" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GridMedia_Adaptive__DataTemplate}" Margin="0 0 -8 -20" SelectionChanged="ListView_MediaLibrary_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource mediaFilesSource}, Mode=OneWay}">
        </controls1:AdaptiveGridView>
```

And this is how we bind the list with the GridView.

---

**Update**

The thumbnail is visible only if I get out from the view by scrolling down, and then scrolling up

**MediaFile.cs**

```
    public class MediaFile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Declare the event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private ImageSource _thumbnail = null;

    public ImageSource Thumbnail
    {
        get { return _thumbnail; }
        set
        {
            _thumbnail = value;
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            OnPropertyChanged("Thumbnail");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    // The calling member's name will be used as the parameter.
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is MediaFile mediaFile &&
               Id == mediaFile.Id;
    }
}
```

}

**GridMedia.xaml UserControl**

```
<UserControl>
<Grid Style="{StaticResource Faves_Grid}">
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="ThumbnailImage" Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid></UserControl>
```

**GridMedia.xaml.cs UserControl**

```
 public sealed partial class GridMedia : UserControl
{
    public GridMedia()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MediaFile Data
    {
        get { return (MediaFile)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(MediaFile), typeof(GridMedia), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(Data_Changed)));

    private static void Data_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue != null && !e.NewValue.Equals(e.OldValue) && e.NewValue is MediaFile data)
        {
            var instance = d as GridMedia;
            // get a bitmapImage through the convert method
            instance.ThumbnailImage.Source = Thumbnail(e.NewValue);
        }
    }

    static ImageSource Thumbnail(object value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value is MediaFile)
            {
                MediaFile file = value as MediaFile;
                //generate Thumbnail
                int width = 160;
                int height = 90;

                var pathFileTemp = $@"{FileLocations.MediaPath}";
                try
                {
                    StorageFile originalFile = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(pathFileTemp + file.Id).AsTask().Result;
                    if (originalFile != null)
                    {
                        //check extention
                        if (file.Extension.ToLower().Contains("pdf"))
                        {
                            GetThumbnailForPDF(file).GetAwaiter();
                            return file.Thumbnail;
                        }
                        else if (file.Extension.ToLower().Contains("jpg") ||
                            file.Extension.ToLower().Contains("gif") ||
                            file.Extension.ToLower().Contains("png") ||
                            file.Extension.ToLower().Contains("jpeg"))
                        {
                            GetThumbnailForImage(file).GetAwaiter();
                            return file.Thumbnail;
                        }
                    }
                    return new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Icon/placeholder_img.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Icon/placeholder_img.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use `Converter` to handle simple conversion instead of asynchronous conversion involving IO.

You can try to convert your `DataTemplate` into `UserControl`, and convert the file operation logic of `Converter` into the callback of dependency property change inside the control.

Please try the following steps:

1. Create a comparison method for the `MediaFile` class (Suppose there is a unique `Id` property)

```cs
public class MediaFile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   //... other code
   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
       return obj is MediaFile mediaFile &&
              Id == mediaFile.Id;
   }
}
```

2. Create a `UserControl`

**MyMediaFileItem.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl
    ...>

    <Grid>
        <!-- your other code -->
        <Image x:Name="ThumbnailImage"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MyMediaFileItem.xaml.cs**

```cs
public MediaFile Data
{
    get { return (MediaFile)GetValue(DataProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(MediaFile), typeof(MyMediaFileItem), new PropertyMetadata(null,new PropertyChangedCallback(Data_Changed)));

private static void Data_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.NewValue!=null && !e.NewValue.Equals(e.OldValue) && e.NewValue is MediaFile data)
    {
        var instance = d as MyMediaFileItem;
        // get a bitmapImage through the convert method
        instance.ThumbnailImage.Source = bitmapImage;
    }
}
```

3. Usage

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="GridMedia_DataTemplate" x:DataType="MediaFile">
    <controls:MyMediaFileItem Data="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to implement it in the next few days.

Comment: Sure, I will wait for your test result.

Comment: @maxmustermann Hi, Do you have solved the problems encountered?

Comment: I will update the question since your solution doesnt work too. The thumbnail is still not loaded

Comment: The thumbnails of the first few items are visible if i scroll down far enough and scroll back up after wards @richard-zhang-msft

Comment: it works now. I just had to make the function ASYNC. Thank you so much